# In Polymer, how can I specify a mixin that will target an element within another element?

Tags: html, polymer

This demo demonstrates my problem: http://jsbin.com/kuxuqa/3/edit?html,output

The background is being applied to both buttons, however the mixin is not being applied to the button that is part of a custom element. How can I declare a mixin that will apply to Button 2?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I was thinking I had to target `paper-button` in my selector. The solution to my example was:

```css
#test {
  --paper-button {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

The key is to avoid use of `/deep/` and `::shadow` (since those will reportedly be deprecated). You should target only **light dom** with your selectors, using mixins to apply custom styling for elements in shadow dom.